# How to shutdown Ubuntu on the computer without power button

Tags: shutdown

I am searching for the way how to shutdown Ubuntu with no use of shutdown command.
I've ever done the shutdown on the computer with power button using `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`
This time, I have to physically shut down on the computer(Advantec EPC-T2285) with the power switch.
But, I don't know how to physically shut down `Ubuntu`.

Please give me the help to do this.

Answer (score 3):

From a terminal / ssh prompt run `sudo shutdown -h now` to power down the server.
Also `poweroff` might work.

Answer (score 1):

As any user as long as that user is the only one logged in it is possible to poweroff as follows as well. `systemctl poweroff`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use sudo `shutdown -h now` or `shutdown -r now`

In order to give you more details please read the Ubuntu [shutdown documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/shutdown.8.html)

```
   -r     Requests that the system be rebooted after it has been brought down.

   -h     Requests  that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought
          down, with the choice as to which left up to the system.
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the model number you provided in your question..`(Advantec EPC-T2285)`
it has power button

[image]

as a example: in Ubuntu 18.10 (may be similar up to some previous versions)
you can configure the options in settings

[image]

once, you configured it to poweroff and once you press physical button
it will prompt you with below options.. you can choose the options immediately or leave it for 60secs so that system will auto powroff..

[image]